# Where do you place POSIX semaphores when using POSIX shared memory?

Tags: ipc, posix, shared-memory, semaphore

I'm trying to build a client server application using POSIX shared memory and POSIX semaphores. Do I have to place the semaphores inside the shared memory segment or can the semaphores just be global variables? I wish to adhere to POSIX convention.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, the semaphores are system resources; you don't have to worry about locating them.

Update: Let me "extend and revise my remarks".  *Named* semaphores are system resources.  Unnamed semaphores must be in a shared memory segment.  See the [intro man page for semaphores](http://linux.die.net/man/7/sem_overview).